# why can genymotion virtual device with api 19 can work with android api 23?

Tags: android, genymotion, android-sdk-2.3

guys. I just installed genymotion and added a virtual android device for testing. now i am very pulzzed by a fact i only installed the android api 22 and 23, the virtual device created by me is Samsung S5 4.4.4 with api 19 but it works well. I think it needs sdk api 19 to run the device but it does not. So can anybody tell me why? Thank you very much!